# Serializing a List<IComparable> member with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize an existing legacy class using `protobuf-net`:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ProtoContract]
public class AttributeValue {

    List<IComparable> attributeValues;

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<IComparable> Values {
        get {
            return this.attributeValues;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an exception saying `No serializer for type System.IComparable is available for model (default)`.
Looking at some examples, I've seen that I should add the `DynamicType = true` property in the `ProtoMember` attribute, but it's now deprecated.
Is there an alternative way to serialize and deserialize a class with a member declared like that?

Comment: I think you should use `ProtoInclude` attribute where you specify possible concrete types.

Comment: I had tried that, but the `ProtoInclude` attribute cannot be used on members, only on classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, fundamentally. Protobuf is predicated on knowing what you're serializing / deserializing *before* you do it, which isn't possible if all you know is `object` or `IComparable`.

I spoke about this situation in more detail last week in [a GitHub issue here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/issues/710#issuecomment-699459902), including recommendations on how I would represent this if it was me, which effectively comes down to "as a discriminated union of the actual types I expect". I would also create a separate DTO model, and serialize *that* rather than trying to serialize my pre-existing type - and then just map between them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I'll try to think of the least painful way to refactor my code :)
It's legacy stuff that I was trying to touch as little as possible, but the serialization of large amounts of data with the standard binary serializers was taking way too much time...